# Adding description text for files in file manager?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I want to add descriptions for each file in the empty red space. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to Windows that will allow you to enter arbitrary text as a file property.

If you right-click the column headings, you can select additional fields.  Some of these fields sometimes provide additional information.  For example, "Comments" and "File description".  However, these are extracted from the metadata for particular file types, and are not a generic mechanism.  Explorer provides no way to add/modify these fields.

There are third-party products which do what you are asking for.  NTFS supports something called "Alternate Data Streams" (ADS), which allows storing arbitrary data under any number of streams.  Explorer can be extended to show this.  The only products I'm familiar with are expensive file classification tools for enterprise networks, but it should be possible to implement a simpler design, too.